# Corda: Cannot connect to server(s)

Tags: corda

I have downloaded the corda example project: `spring-observable-stream` and try to run it from IntelliJ. While started the server, It gives error:

> W 11:01:55 1 AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'nodeRPCConnection' defined in file [C:\Corda\spring-observable-stream\server\out\production\classes\net\corda\server\NodeRPCConnection.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [net.corda.server.NodeRPCConnection]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the nodes before you start the servers. See the instructions here: https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html#running-the-example-cordapp.

Comment: Thank you. my nodes were not started properly. Restarted my machine and works fine now. Appreciate your prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue with the `cordapp-example` on the Mac. I found that running the `runnodes` command in headless mode worked for me as per the instructions here: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/tutorial-cordapp.html#running-the-example-cordapp-2